# HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request Eclipse

Tags: java, tcp

Trying to programm sockets with TDP and there´s some mistake in the http client that I can´t find that bring an error when I run it.

```
package tcp.client;


import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.SocketException;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

import edu.uoc.dpcs.lsim.logger.LoggerManager.Level;
import lsim.library.api.LSimLogger;


public class HTTPclient {

    public HTTPclient() {
    }
            
    public String head(String http_server_address, int http_server_port){
        LSimLogger.log(Level.INFO, "start HTTPclient.head ");
        LSimLogger.log(Level.INFO, "HTTP server_address: " + http_server_address);
        LSimLogger.log(Level.INFO, "HTTP server_port: "    + http_server_port);

        /* Complete code  */
        
        String peticio = "HEAD /xai/xai.html HTTP/1.1\r\nAccept\r\n";

        LSimLogger.log(Level.INFO, peticio);

        String resposta = "";
        Socket socket;
        try {
            socket = new Socket(http_server_address, http_server_port);
            LSimLogger.log(Level.INFO, "Socket created");
            OutputStream output = socket.getOutputStream();
            PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(output, true);
            writer.println(peticio);
            LSimLogger.log(Level.INFO, "Request sent");

            BufferedReader inputFromServer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
            String linia ;
            while ((linia = inputFromServer.readLine()) != null) {
                resposta += linia + "\r\n";
                LSimLogger.log(Level.TRACE, linia);
            }
            
            socket.close();

            LSimLogger.log(Level.INFO, "Response: " + resposta);
        } catch (SocketException e) {
            LSimLogger.log(Level.FATAL, e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            LSimLogger.log(Level.FATAL, e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            LSimLogger.log(Level.FATAL, e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        
        return resposta;
    }
}
```

The code was done and according to the test question I only had to write the code where it says String peticio.

The error message.

HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request

Any help?

Comment: Doesn't Accept take an argument? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Accept

Answer (score 0):

End of line on message must be either hardcoded or added by printer

```
String peticio = "HEAD /xai/xai.html HTTP/1.1\r\nAccept\r\n";
// println will send OS end-of-line so it might be just \n or \r
// better not depend on that
writer.print(peticio);
writer.print("\r\n");
```

Or

```
    writer.print("HEAD /xai/xai.html HTTP/1.1\r\n");
    writer.print("Accept\r\n");
    writer.print("\r\n");
```

Or

```
    writer.printf("%s\r\n", "HEAD /xai/xai.html HTTP/1.1");
    writer.printf("%s\r\n", "Accept");
    writer.printf("%s\r\n", "");
```

Comment: You mean that add all in one line like (String peticio = "HEAD /xai/xai.html HTTP/1.0\r\nAccept:html\r\n\r\n";), I tried and it didn´t work either

Comment: Message must end with double \r\n but `writer.println(peticio);` could be sending `\r\n\n` depending on the operating system. That would work on window$.

Comment: when you say writer.print, is any other way for java?

Comment: writer.printf as shown in the answer